# How to get GoogleMap v2 server key in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I need to show nearby places in my GoogleMap. Now I am using api key for getting nearby places. But it throws error. So how to get server key in updated Google api console screen. In that there is no option like "server key". Anybody have an idea just share your thoughts. Thanks

I am using the below code:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location="
                            + latitude
                            + ","
                            + +longitude
                            + "&radius=3446&types=hospital&"
                            + "key="apikey""+"&sensor=true
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to register your project on google's developer's console. here is the link for the same and there you will find your server key.

Hope this helps you

https://console.developers.google.com/start

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Server Key in the Developer's Console. Go to API Manager > Credentials > Create credentials > API Key > Server Key.

You can also refer/follow [Get a key for Google Places API Web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) which is the API for place search you are using.

Comment: This may also be part of V3. You may want to upgrade the latest version.